# Ruby (Rails) DRY - Function pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using ruby on rails for a project and noticed I'm using some pattern on my functions that goes like this:

```
begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        #some database manipulation
    end
    return true
rescue
    return false
end
```

So I would like to DRY my code, in a way that only that #some database manipulation is gonna change. Any ideas of how I could do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue with "naked rescues" like this is that it can be hard to separate the expected errors, and the non-expected ones. What is your use-case for this? Why would it not suffice to use the built in validation functionality of ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a method like this:

```
def with_transaction
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    yield
  end
  return true
rescue 
  return false
end
```

And then use it like:

```
with_transaction do 
  # some db manipulation
end
```

But generally I would advise against silencing errors like that.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Yeah, I know that sillent rescue is not good, but it's for an app, and in case the return is false, I have some default message error. Anyway, I'm gonna call that in some of my models, so where should I put that "with_transaction" function?

Comment: You could: A.) create a concern and included it in the models you're using. B.) dynamically augment `ActiveRecord::Base`. C.) add it to `ApplicationRecord` (rails 5). Or create a an abstract model, from which all your models inherit.

Comment: Add it to ApplicationRecord seems a good option. Thank you so much!

Comment: Using a blind `rescue` ("Pokémon exception handling", catch them all!) is a really bad idea. Do try and rescue *only* those things related to transaction issues, let the rest flutter up. Paving over problems with a boolean is how severe problems fester in your code without anyone knowing anything is wrong.

Comment: Hahaha nice joke. Thanks @tadman, I'm really gonna do something about that!